# What is the difference between mindfulness and concentration?

Tags: theravada

Does the concentration occurs during first jhana?or is it relates to the samadhi which involves in second jhana?What is actually one pointed of the mind means?

Answer (score 2):

"*Mindfulness*" means to "*remember to apply*" and "*not forget*" the Dhamma teachings. To quote:

> *What is sammasati? Sati means to bear in mind or bring to mind. Sati is the state of recollecting, the state of remembering, the state of
>   non-fading, the state of non-forgetting. [Vbh.105, 286]*
>
> ---
>
> *One is mindful to abandon wrong view & to enter & remain in right view: This is one's right mindfulness. Thus these three qualities —
>   right view, right effort & right mindfulness — run & circle around
>   right view. MN 117*

For example, in Buddhist meditation, it means to always remember to keep the mind free from craving. The suttas (MN 10; MN 118) say the meditator: "*is mindful to abandon covetousness & distress in relation to the world*".

"*Concentration*" is the state of non-distractedness or singular preoccuption; which occurs when the mind is continuously mindful. Concentration is "samadhi' ("collectedness"); when the mind gathers its potentials onto a primary task and objective.

Every jhana has one-pointedness/singleness of mind; as follows:

> *The first jhana has five factors. There is the case where, in a monk who has attained the five-factored first jhana, there occurs directed
>   thought, evaluation, rapture, pleasure & **singleness of mind**. MN 43*
>
> ---
>
> *Unflagging persistence was aroused in me, and unmuddled mindfulness established. My body was calm & unaroused, my mind concentrated &
>   **single**. Quite withdrawn from sensuality, withdrawn from unskillful
>   mental qualities, I entered & remained in the first jhana... MN 19*
>
> ---
>
> *And what is the faculty of concentration? There is the case where a monk, a disciple of the noble ones, making it his object to let go,
>   attains concentration, attains **singleness of mind**. Quite withdrawn
>   from sensuality, withdrawn from unskillful mental qualities, he enters
>   & remains in the first jhana... SN 48.10*

One-pointedness is when the mind becomes glued to a mental image.

Both the 1st and 2nd jhana have one-pointedness however in the 1st jhana, while the "centre" of the mind is unmoving; the outer parts of the mind (consciousness; not thoughts) still move or 'hover' around the factors of jhana; similar to how a wheel is fixed to an axle but spins around the axle. Refer to Ajahn Brahm's teaching about the "*jhana wobble*".

On Buddhist chatsites on the internet, there is not one person who has declared they have attained jhana who has actually attained jhana. These people are always overestimating their experiences.

Comment: Your definition of concentration is spot on, imho.

Answer (score 1):

Concentration is part of every mind state: the normal, regular, every-day-of-life mind states; the unwholesome ones; the wholesome ones.
It is absolutely not limited to jhana states!

One-pointed means basically that it focusses the entire mind on to an object. In vipassana we speak of momentary one-pointedness where the mind in this moment focusses entirely on this object and the next moment on the next object.